# (Vue) I can't get existing data to show up in an edit form

Tags: vue.js

I have a site that allows CRUD operations, and right now I have a page display a document and the data that I have put inside it, and blow the document there is a form where I can enter new data and update the document.
But this is not very practical from a UI perspective.
I would prefer if I could display the existing data INSIDE the form that I use to update.

I hope I am making it clear?
Instead of having a blank form, where I just enter some new data, I would like the existing data to be shown inside the form, in case I just want to edit a single line of text or something like that.

Below I will show you the code, and then I will show you what I tried to do to solve this problem.

The composable handles the update function itself:

```
const useDocument = (collection, id) => {
const error = ref(null)
const isPending = ref(false)

let docRef = projectFirestore.collection(collection).doc(id)

const updateDoc = async (updates) => {
    isPending.value = true
    error.value = null
    try {
        const res = await docRef.update(updates) 
        isPending.value = false
        return res
    }catch(err) {
        console.log(err.message)
        isPending.value = false
        error.value = 'Could not update document'
    }
}
```

Then I have a component where I update the existing document using a form

```
template>
    <div class="Hero-Section-Edit">
      <form @submit.prevent="handleSubmit">
      <input type="text" required placeholder="Change title" v-model="title">
            <label>Change image</label>
      <input type="file" @change="handleChange">
      <div class="error">{{ fileError }}</div>
      <button v-if="!isPending">Update</button>
      <button v-else disabled>Updating...</button>
   </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { ref } from 'vue'
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router' 
import useDocument from '@/composables/useDocument'
import useStorage from '@/composables/useStorage'
import useCollection from '@/composables/useCollection'
export default {
    props: ['content'],
    setup(props) {
        const title = ref('')
        const { filePath, url, uploadImage } = useStorage()
        const file = ref(null)
        const fileError = ref(null)
        const { error } = useCollection()
        const isPending = ref(false)
        const router = useRouter();

        const handleSubmit = async () => {
    if (!props.content) return
    const { updateDoc } = useDocument('gershoej', props.content.id)
            await uploadImage(file.value)
            await updateDoc({
                title: title.value,
                imageUrl: url.value,
                filePath: filePath.value,
            })
                isPending.value = false
                if(!error.value) {
                router.push({ name: "Home" })
             }
        }

        // allowed file types

       const types = ['image/png', 'image/jpeg']

       const handleChange = (e) => {
          const selected = e.target.files[0]
          console.log(selected)

          if (selected && types.includes(selected.type)) {
             file.value = selected
             fileError.value = null 
          } else {
             file.value = null
             fileError.value = 'Please select an image of the type JPG or PNG'
          }
       }

        return {
            title,
            url,
            handleSubmit,
            handleChange,
            fileError,
            isPending,
            error
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Finally, I have a component where I view the document and import the update form.

```
<template>
        <div v-if="content" class="Hero-Section-Details">
                    <img :src="content.imageUrl">
                    <h2> {{ content.title }}</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button @click="handleDelete">Delete</button>
        <HeroSectionEdit :content="content" />
</template>

<script>
import HeroSectionEdit from './HeroSectionEdit'
import useDocument from '@/composables/useDocument'
import getDocument from '@/composables/getDocument'
import useStorage from '@/composables/useStorage'
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";
export default {
    props: ['id'],
    components: { HeroSectionEdit },
    setup(props) {
        const { document: content } = getDocument('gershoej', props.id)
        const { deleteDoc } = useDocument('gershoej', props.id)
        const router = useRouter();
        const { deleteImage } = useStorage()

      const handleDelete = async () => {
          await deleteImage(content.value.filePath)
          await deleteDoc()
          confirm('Do you wish to delete this content?')
          router.push({ name: "Home" });
      }

        return {
            content,
            handleDelete
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

What I tried to do was to add content.title to the form instead of just title.

```
v-model="content.title"
```

This DOES actually make the existing data appear inside the form, but I am getting an error:
**Cannot read property 'title' of null**
and I am not able to update the file.

Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are rendering the component before `content` is fetched from getDocument (I guess it's returning a promise).

You need to make sure you have an actual object in content, before accessing its properties.